# Jekyll serving to a subdirectory

Tags: jekyll

I can only get Jekyll to serve my blog in the root directory: `localhost:4000`

When I give a baseurl as shown below in my `_config.yml`, jekyll says it is serving my blog at `http://0.0.0.0:4000/press`, however, I can never reach it in my browser at `localhost:4000/press`.

```
# Site settings
title: Your Awesome Blog
email: your-email@domain.com
description: "Write an awesome description for your new site here"
baseurl: "/press"
url: ""

# Build settings
markdown: rdiscount
relative_permalinks: true
permalink: date

rdiscount:
    extensions: [footnotes, autolink, smart]
```

Am I missing something?
Thank you! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`0.0.0.0:4000` and `localhost:4000` are not the same location.

You can use `jekyll serve --host localhost` or you can add a line with `host: localhost` to your `_config.yml`

Comment: That did it. Thanks for the help; I can't believe I overlooked that.